# Add an express use handler that changes the base route

Tags: node.js, express, svelte, sveltekit

I have a svelte/sveltekit app. It says you could just your app like so

```
import { handler } from './build/handler.js';
app.use(handler);
```

But I already have another app in this express server, eg

```
app.use(otherhandler)
```

So I was hoping there was a way to do this

```
app.use('/newapp', svelte)
```

And it works, but, my svelte app has an auto redirect to `/login` if you are not logged in. So then the express app immediately redirects to `/login` whereas I was hoping it would go to `/newapp/login`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

When you have a different base, you probably should configure that via [`config.kit.paths.base`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#paths) which then can be imported from [`$apps/path`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-paths-base) and added to the various links and redirects (at the very least in the UI this will be necessary, as stated by the docs).